# Make div appear on the bottom of the page in every browser

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with known content in top and bottom parts of the page, and unknown middle section. The middle part can be as short as 100px or more than a 1000px in height.

To make a middle part `min-height: 100%;` **is not an option**.

I found a good answer to my problem:

```css
        html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        body{
            min-height:100%;
            display:table;
        }
        .top{
            display:block;
        }
        .main{
            display:block;
        }
        .buttom{
            display:table-footer-group;
        }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="top">
 Fixed top box
  </div>
  <div class="main">
 Box with unknown content
  </div>
  <div class="buttom">
 Fixed buttom box
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work in mozila browser. Can anyone suggest something that works in every browser?

To clarify: **All div supposed to be separate and in no case should one div appear on top another**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `height:100%;` increases height in mozilla.

```css
        html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        body{
            min-height:100%;
            display:table;
              height:100%;
        }
        .top{
            display:block;
        }
        .main{
            display:block;
        }
        .buttom{
            display:table-footer-group;
              height: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="top">
 Fixed top box
  </div>
  <div class="main">
 Box with unknown content
  </div>
  <div class="buttom">
 Fixed buttom box
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. Use `position:fixed` and `bottom:0`.
In this case independent of any other elements in the page , your bottom will always appear `0px` from the bottom of the page.

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  background: red
}
.main {
  /* style for main */
}
.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #444;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    Fixed top box
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Box with unknown content
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Fixed buttom box
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In case you are not looking for fixed bottom you can implement the same using `javascript`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var mainHeight = $(".main").height();
  var topHeight = $(".top").height();
  var bottomHeight = $(".bottom").height();
  if ((windowHeight - (topHeight + bottomHeight)) > mainHeight) {
    $(".bottom").css("position", "fixed");
  } else {
    $(".bottom").css("position", "initial");
  }
});
```

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  background: red
}
.main {
  height: 10px;
}
.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #444;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    Fixed top box
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Box with unknown content
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Fixed buttom box
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't work! if the middle part height more than a window height then fixed bottom div will be on middle part

Comment: Isn't that what you want. You have mentioned fixed bottom in the question. What exactly should the behaviour be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can position by absolute to bottom.

```css
        html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        body{
            min-height:100vh;
            display:table;
        }
        .top{
            display:block;
        }
        .main{
            display:block;
        }
        .buttom{
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
        }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="top">
 Fixed top box
  </div>
  <div class="main">
 Box with unknown content
  </div>
  <div class="buttom">
 Fixed buttom box
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```